# loop message in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using inspect element console on facebook.com and I am sending messages through this javascript script :

```
var o = document.getElementsByClassName("uiTextareaAutogrow _552m");

// set the chat textbox
var chatTextBox = o[0];

// set the message value
chatTextBox.value = "Hello";

// create a keydown event    
var e = new Event("keydown");

// it has to simulate the Enter press (key code is 13)
e.keyCode = 13;

// trigger it
chatTextBox.dispatchEvent(e);
```

this script sends 1 normal message. Is there any way to create a loop of messages to send them many times?

Comment: what is the use case for sending multiple message? sounds like you are trying to spam.

Comment: I am asking just for knowledge. I am not a spammer

Comment: then resarch loops in javascript ;)

Comment: btw, this would even be illegal with only one message, you should read the platform policy of facebook. prefilling is not allowed.

Comment: I have researched a lot on google but I cant find things that fits best. My last hope is stack only. And, i am not a spammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I cant tell you the exact answer as this would result in spamming, so just go to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp for help in loops.
Hope I helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: i am new here i will keep this in mind next time sorry :P

Comment: To expand upon @kleopatra's comment, please edit your current answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this at the beginning 
window.onload=my_code();

and this at the end
location.reload();

Comment: I cant understand. I am asking a way to create a loop so that i can send the user unlimited/many messages